# Push notifications are being sent only from 5 apps

Tags: xiaomi, push-notifications

I have bought yesterday a Xiaomi Redmi 3S. For some reason I get push notifications only from 5 apps: Whatsapp, Facebook, Allo, Gmail and Outlook. I don't get push notifications from any other apps.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Turn on auto start for apps. 
Go to Security  - > Permissions - > Autostart. 
And select apps that you want to get notifications.